# Laravel 5.5 - where access relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5.5 I am trying to get all members where `member->user->membership->id` is `user->membership->id`. For example:

```
$members = Member::where($member->user->membership->id,$user->membership->id)->get();
```

Obviously `$member` is not set yet. So, how can I access this relationship?

Functions already defined in Models:

**Member**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'account_id');
}
```

**Membership**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

**User**

```
public function membership() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Membership');
}

public function member() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Member','account_id');
}
```

Comment: Post your structure of the both models (user and member)or what ever models(tables) do you have. Please. And we have eager loading that help fetch all the related data from a relation dont worry about that.

Comment: the basic q is how to do a where with a foreign key relationship (belongsTo?) using the model query builder, i think a good q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whereHas to do this:

```
Member::whereHas('user', function($q) use ($user) {
    $q->where('membership_id', $user->membership_id);
})->get();
```

I'm supposing you have `membership_id` in User model, since you are calling `user->membership->id`.

And you need the relation between Member and User to be defined. Something like this (in Member Model), but considering that you are following the naming convention:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: nice. and this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: Actually, there are several ways to do this. My answer is just one of them. :)